# how to force gradle application plugin to (not) use the already bundled jar

Tags: java, gradle

When building an [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) with the application gradle plugin, I get a tarball that contains:

- `app/` with all content from `build/classes` and `build/resources`
- `lib/` all dependend modules
- `bin/` with the generated start scripts, where classpath contains `app/` and (not included) `lib/project-version.jar`

Problem: Jar might be hooked from other plugins, I want to use Jar in the application.

so:

How can I force application to bundle the jar, not the extracted class files only?

sidekick: 
With would also allow to bundle shadowJar'ed applications ... I it would be possible to take incluence in how dependencies are resolved (I don't need any more since they are in the uber'fat'Jar)

P.S: inverted question would make more sense: how NOT to include the jar / shadowJar in the application but use the same content as in the Jar bundle - so ratpack does ([in a bad way](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/blob/master/ratpack-gradle/src/main/groovy/ratpack/gradle/RatpackPlugin.groovy))

Comment: The behavior you are seeing doesn't align with the behavior I am seeing.  I have things added to the manifest with `jar { manifest { attributes("foo": "bar") } }` and when I do `./gradlew installDist`, the manifest in `lib/project.jar` contains `foo: bar`.  Do you happen to have a repro case on GitHub that shows the problem?

Comment: mhh ... that's reasonable that your `lib/project.jar` contains a manifest, but for me there is no `lib/project.jar` ... all project dependend assets are in `app` and are not bundled as jar for the distribution tarball. but yes, I will come up soon with an example project for that ...

Comment: ohh ... kay ... it's caused by ratpack for me: https://gist.github.com/childnode/d96c084ac088d2d94b44
This plugin hooks into the distribution and doesn't reuse the jar... I'll file a bug on them.